# Is it possible to "link" existing iPhone and iPad app versions to create a universal one? AS3

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript

I have created and released an application in AS3 using Flash. I'm now wanting to make it a universal application. I have two .fla files with the full apps ready to go in them. What I'd like to know is if there is a way I can simply link the two together, instead of going through a much longer process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to copy all the frames from the iPad version(plus code on frames, and library files) to the iPhone version, and then at the very first frame of your project, get the device info (like the screen height, width - I don't really know what the possibilities are), and then skip to the iPad frames if the device appears to be an iPad, or just go to the iPhone frames if it appears to be an iPhone.

---

A little drawing to make it clear:

(frames:)

|1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10

```
^      
checking device(frame 1)
```

|1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10

```
  ^      
  iPhone version(frame 2 till 6)
```

|1||2||3||4||5||6||7||8||9||10

```
          ^      
          iPad version(frame 7 till 10)
```

---